# Javascript can't acces to HTML(moving object left-right)

Tags: javascript, html

my file:

```
index.html
client
   css
     style.css
   js
     javascript.js
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>blablabla</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/javascript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
     <div id="guy"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript.js

```
var guy=document.getElementById('guy');
var container=document.getElementById('container');

var guyLeft=0;

function anim(e){
if(e.keyCode==39){
    guyLeft +=2;
    guy.style.left = guyLeft + 'px';

}
if(e.keyCode==37){
    guyLeft -=2;
    guy.style.left = guyLeft + 'px';
}   
}
document.onkeydown =anim;
```

style.css

```
#container{
height:400px;
width:600px;
outline:1px solid black;
position: relative;
}
#guy{
position: absolute;
height:50px;
width:50px;
outline:1px solid black;
background-color:red;
left:0;
}
```

1)So guys pls help.. I just want to move object left and right .. when i put that code between   in index.html it works but in seperate javascript.js class doesn't work. Thx for help.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. http://codepen.io/DanielTate/pen/RaVaLQ
Make sure your javascript is loaded after the document right before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You have to load the JavaScript at the bottom of the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>blablabla</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="guy"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2) Move up and down:

```
var guy = document.getElementById('guy');
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var guyLeft = 0;
var guyTop = 0;

function anim(e){
    if(e.keyCode==39){
        guyLeft +=2;
        guy.style.left = guyLeft + 'px';

    }
    if(e.keyCode==37){
        guyLeft -=2;
        guy.style.left = guyLeft + 'px';
    }

    // UP
    if(e.keyCode==38) {
        guyTop -=2;
        guy.style.top = guyTop + 'px';
    }

    // DOWN
    if(e.keyCode==40) {
        guyTop +=2;
        guy.style.top = guyTop + 'px';
    }
}

document.onkeydown = anim;
```

You should use the [console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) if you want to catch bugs and errors in JavaScript.

Comment: thx it works now .. im sorry im new on javascript thx for console tip ^^

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan hej no offense im new here on stack overflow .. is now oke i put answer for correnct .. peace :)